# EasyAdminBundle doesn't load assets

Tags: php, symfony, assets, easyadmin

I am trying to set up Symfony project on prod server and everything works fine except this one thing. I am using EasyAdminBundle for admin panel and there is something like this:
[image: my website without assets]

It looks like my assets didn't load at all. But I had all the files in web/assets

```
$ ls web/assets/ -l
    total 1548
    drwxr-xr-x 3 andar-krakow andar-krakow    4096 2019-01-12 11:48 elfinder
    drwxr-xr-x 2 andar-krakow andar-krakow    4096 2019-01-12 11:48 jquery
    drwxr-xr-x 4 andar-krakow andar-krakow    4096 2019-01-12 11:48 jquery-ui
    -rw-r--r-- 1 andar-krakow andar-krakow 1381670 2019-01-12 11:48 require-built.js
    -rw-r--r-- 1 andar-krakow andar-krakow     733 2019-01-12 11:48 require.config.js
    -rw-r--r-- 1 andar-krakow andar-krakow   99864 2019-01-12 11:48 require.css
    -rw-r--r-- 1 andar-krakow andar-krakow   81836 2019-01-12 11:48 require.js
```

I also try to use `php bin/console assets:install` and `php bin/console assets:install --symlink`, but it didn't work. Maybe there is something config I forgot or there is a problem with permissions. When I use assets:install , there is something like this:

```
$ php bin/console assets:install

Installing assets as hard copies.


[OK] No assets were provided by any bundle.
```

I have assetic bundle installed, project based on Symfony 3.4, EasyAdminBundle 1.17

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I looked on js console and checked which files can't be loaded. There was missing a `public/` folder in `vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/Resources/`
 where all needed files schould be. I uploaded them from my local machine and it works.

Did someone knows why composer install don't always include all necessary files?

Comment: Assets should be installed via `bin/console assets:install` that, as you mentioned, should be run by Composer already.
But I am not sure the assets are supposed to be put in `public` directly (e.g. what if they need to be compiled from SASS/SCSS first?).